# Unable to inject Services in .run in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I want to inject service into my `.run` block, but when I inject it I cannot use them.

My code is :

```
.run(['AuthFactory', function ($state, $rootScope, AuthFactory, $location) {

    console.log("Auth Factory :%O", AuthFactory);

    AuthFactory.registerUserChangeHandler(function (currentUser) {
        $rootScope.currentUser = currentUser;
    });

    AuthFactory.refresh().then(function (currentUser) {
        console.log("Current User is", currentUser);
    }, function (reason) {
       // User is not Logged in
       $location.path("login");

    });
}]);
```

When I write this code I get error :

> "app.js:120Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'registerUserChangeHandler' of undefined"

If I simply inject `AuthFactory` in function then everything works fine, but now I want to inject `UserService` & use methods inside the service.

I tried injecting it in function but I am unable to use it.

Open for all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake is,if you use array way of dependency injection , than you need to follow the sequence. For example as $state if first value in array, than inside controller callback the first value will represent $state.

```
.run(['$state','$rootScope','AuthFactory','$location', function ($state, $rootScope, AuthFactory, $location) {
            console.log("Auth Factory :%O", AuthFactory);
//                UserService.login({
//                    'username': "guest",
//                    'password': "guest"
//                }, function () {
//                    $state.go("corporate_site.home", {reload:'true'});
//                }, function () {
//                    $rootScope.error = "Login Failed. Invalid Credentials.";
//                });
//                $state.go("corporate_site.home", {reload: 'true'});

          AuthFactory.registerUserChangeHandler(function (currentUser) {
            $rootScope.currentUser = currentUser;
        });

        AuthFactory.refresh().then(function (currentUser) {
            console.log("Current User is", currentUser);
            }, function (reason) {

//                User is not Logged in
                $location.path("login");

            });
        }]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You mess up in DI.

```
.run(['state', '$rootScope', 'AuthFactory', '$location', 
    function ($state, $rootScope, AuthFactory, $location) {

        console.log("Auth Factory :%O", AuthFactory);
        // ...
    }]);
```